# Excel like calculation in R

Tags: r

I am given two first values of vector. I want to calculate next value of vector from two previous ones. It's like you do in excel : fill first two cells with numbers, write formula in third cell and then apply it for further cells. But, i want to do it without a loop.

Thing i want to do :

```
x = c()
x[1] = 1
x[2] = 2
for (i in 3:10)
    x[i] = 2*x[i-1] - 0.5*x[i-2]

x

> x
 [1]   1.0000   2.0000   3.5000   6.0000  10.2500  17.5000  29.8750  51.0000
 [9]  87.0625 148.6250
>
```

I want to use previous values of vector in calculations of current value, but not the way i just did.

Comment: Do you want to do it without a loop in the background or without *writing* a loop?  Can you give us an example of the values you might be working with and how you would like the rest calculated?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code?

Comment: Actually i am working with matrix. I just want to get the idea. Is it possible to use previous values of vector in calculating current values. But not using a loop this way : for(i in 3:10) x[i] = 2*x[i-1] + 0.5*x[i-2].

Comment: please edit your question, providing R code that re-creates your exact input, and then give a clear example of your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the ith element of the series without looping like this:

```
roots <- polyroot( c(0.5, -2, 1) )
roots <- Re(roots)

k <- solve( rbind( 1, roots ), c(1,2) )

genfun <- function(n) {
    as.vector(k %*% roots^(n-1))
}

genfun(1)
genfun(2)
genfun(3)
genfun(4)
```

it is easier to compare to the loop if we do something like:

```
genfun2 <- Vectorize(genfun)
genfun2( 1:10 )
```

However while not using explicit loops there are several uses of loops (`:` uses an internal loop, then `mapply` is used internally which loops as well), so this does not quite fit the "no loops" requirement.  Even if we type by hand 'genfun(1)`,`genfun(2)`,`genfun(3)`, ... then we are using wetware looping even if not forcing the computer to loop, so I don't know if that counts or not.

Personally, looping seems the simpler option to me.  And if you pre allocate the entire vector and write an efficient loop, then looping is probably not going to be any slower than other approaches.

**Edit**

Actually you could also do this using a recursive function (and store all the intermediate calculations).  I'm not sure if that would be considered to be "Without loops" or not.  Either way I expect that it would be more complicated and slower than the simple looping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer, because I think the answer to your question "is it possible" is "no."

As far as I know, this is impossible to do without looping (at least in the background), because you need to re-poll the new values for each successive step.  In Excel, I know the "autofill" option you're referring to, and it is looping in the background.

Even using calculating lag as in the 'embed' function, you will still have to call the function again each time you update a previous value.  As I see it, the logic of what you want to do is fundamentally a loop, unless you want to write each line by hand.  I don't know of any vectorized approach that would work for you, since a vectorized statement would have to do all of the work at once.